# Firefox unloads modules loaded with Components.utils.import()?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

When leaving Firefox running for some time the strange thing begin to happen with my extension. Here's some code, that I need to describe the problem:

*extension.js*

var My = {};

*overlay.js*

Components.utils.import("resource://myextension/extension.js");

```
My.extension = (function() {
  var someFunc = function() {
    // more code
    My.module.otherFunc();
  };

  // more code
})();
```

At some point we start getting the strange error: **'My' is undefined in overlay.js:6**

My guess is that Firefox unloads extension.js module silently, otherwise I couldn't find any hint why this may happen. Do you?

Firefox version: 3.x

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get your extension.js, have you exported symbols at all? Is that the whole file? Also, is overlay.js overlay of the browser?

Comment: Yes, I export symbols from extension.js (it's a stripped version). The code works correctly, but at some time stops working (gives mentioned undefined symbol error)

Comment: Cool, are you opening new windows/closing windows before leaving it idle for a while? I mean, have you tried reproducing this without involving waiting time?

Comment: It's possible that during this time some windows where opened/closed.

Comment: My theory is that when you open new window your "My" is recreated. When you close that new window, "My" in the old one becomes undefined. Can you try that? (if it doesn't prove to be true from first try different combinations of opening and closing windows)

Comment: I've just checked, and `someFunc` can be called only in context of open window.

Comment: When you say "in context of open window" do you mean in the new window you can call it but in the old one you get error calling it?

Comment: @Mihailo, `someFunc` is called from the "onclick" handler, that means that the window is still open, right?

Comment: If you open 2 different windows - you go to File -> New Window (or Ctrl+N). Can you do click without problems in both of the windows? When you close the second window can you still click without problems in the first window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can pass functions to modules as temporary callbacks, you should take steps to ensure that they are not used after the window is closed, because then all its global variables, including `My`, are deleted. If the module subsequently tries to call the function then you will get the error as described.

Comment: I don't understand this. If extension runs in a browser chrome context, the "My" variable is bound to the chrome browser, isn't it? How closing window may dispose this variable?

Comment: @spektom Closing a window deletes all variables defined in the window. It does not delete variables defined in the module, but this isn't where your error is occurring.

Comment: `someFunc` is called from the "onclick" handler, that means that the window is still open, right?

Comment: @spektom But not necessarily the one that added the function to the My variable in the first place.